# Is it possible to use size classes to adjust the text size for UISegmentedControl objects?

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol, size-classes

My app doesn't look good on large screens.  On my main screen, I use a segmented control and on an iPad (Mini), it looks unprofessional, because the text size doesn't scale up in these segmented controls.  The segmented control itself is easy enough to enlarge by setting constraints tying it on the left and right to the superview.

When I try to use size classes, I can't find a way to increase the font size in my segmented control for larger (regular width, any height) screens.  I've tried this in a one screen throw-away app for learning purposes.  I'm new to size classes, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Is there a way to scale up the font size on segmented controls using size classes?  If not, is there another way to do this programmatically?  I'm using Swift and am not familiar with Objective-C.  If you can spell out any solutions in detail, that would help, since I'm still relatively new to iOS programming.

Comment: Welcome! Could you please post a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this with size classes, since you can't set the text size in IB. You can modify the titles in code using `setTitleTextAttributes(_ attributes: , forState state:)`

Comment: @Captain Thanks for the welcome!  Since it is a question only about size classes and segmented controls, there really was no code at all when the question was asked.  I did end up using setTitleTextAttributes in my final solution.  See comments below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use size classes in Interface Builder to substitute a *different* segmented control with a larger font size when you're running on iPad as opposed to iPhone. But you cannot use size class in Interface Builder just to set a different font size on the *same* segmented control.

Comment: Thanks Matt!  I was able to use this (and a few other tidbits around StackOverflow) to get to a solution.  Final Code used:      import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var bigFontSize : CGFloat = 20.0
        var attr = NSDictionary(object: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(bigFontSize), forKey: NSFontAttributeName)
        iPadSegControl.setTitleTextAttributes(attr as [NSObject : AnyObject], forState: .Normal)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var iPadSegControl: UISegmentedControl!